# ReactJS - How to Handle Image Orientation with EXIF tags

Tags: image, reactjs, firebase, exif

What's the best way to orient images in React that contain EXIF data?

I see there are a number of libraries, but their implementation isn't great with ReactJS.

[bluimp/Javascript-Load-Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image)

[exif-js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js)

This comes in light of uploading photos to Firebase from mobile and not having them oriented correctly on web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite some open issues, the library https://github.com/rricard/react-exif-orientation-img works fairly well, as far as I can tell. Does that meet your needs?